# Setting up what's needed for android programming in windows 10?

Tags: android, eclipse

Where can I download proper version of :

1. Eclipse with SDK
2. Youwave
3. Java

All for windows 10 (64bit).

My tools of previous version were working normaly on win7 (32bit). Now in win10 I've downloaded what is recommended on the web for Android programming in win10 but they don't work correctly.

Comment: What problems do you have with them?

Comment: why do not you go android studio, eclipse is getting Retried for android development

Answer (score 0):

Try Android Studio, which is an official development tool for Android. Eclipse with Android SDK (or ADT) will become more and more outdate from an Android development point of view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, are you sure if I got Android Studio every thing will be ok ? I didn't use that . Is it work insted  of all 3 above (eClipse,SDK,youwave). You mean Android Studio is an complete and independent IDE for android programers ?

Comment: Well everything is bundled there, try it and let know if everything is OK on Win10. I cannot say that for 100% your problems will be solved, but it's worth a try.

Comment: The version I said was wrong. I downloaded and installed the Android Studio 2.1.3 on two laptops with windows 10, one with core i7 (with VT-x) processor and second one with core 2 duo processor (without VT-x ).  But none of them could make a simple (one activity app) apk file.

Comment: Do you have a skye or whatsapp id in order to call ? My skype id is: Jalalkaviany     I prefer to have a voice call.